# how to change of text in datagrid after selecting a row only, FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to change the selected row text color in datagrid.
The selected row text color should look different form rest of row.

Comment: Be more specific, which datagrid are you using and what have you tried? Have you even googled for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

See: [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html).

You can change styles in declaration tag or in CSS or in AS3.

For example, for "Spark" and "Mobile Spark" themes:

```
<s:DataGrid selectionColor="#FFCC00">
```

Also see ["Styling rows and columns" docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_04.html) for old Flex 3.x if needed.